# How can I optimize this R code to speed the processing and maybe avoid the loop?

Tags: r, optimization

I have the following code, which is working:

```
period <- 3600000
timeticks <- c(1552820400000, 1552824000000, 1552827600000)
data <- structure(list(start = c(1552820400000, 1552820460000, 1552820520000, 1552824000000, 1513846500000, 1552827720000), 
                       close = c(1552820459999, 1552820519999, 1513846579999, 1552824059999, 1513846559999, 1552827779999),
                       value = c(0.0012,  0.004, 0.0011, 0.00125, 0.0014, 0.0018)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
                  class = "data.frame")
rows <- list()
for (i in 1:length(timeticks)) {
  minIndex = min(which(data$start >= timeticks[i][1] & data$close <= (timeticks[i][1]+period-1), arr.ind = TRUE))
  maxIndex = max(which(data$start >= timeticks[i][1] & data$close <= (timeticks[i][1]+period-1), arr.ind = TRUE))
  if (is.infinite(minIndex) || is.infinite(maxIndex)) {
    newRow <- data.frame(start=timeticks[i][1], close=(timeticks[i][1]+period-1))
  } else {
    newRow <- data.frame(highest=as.character(max(data$value[minIndex:maxIndex])), lowest=as.character(min(data$value[minIndex:maxIndex])), start=timeticks[i][1], end=(timeticks[i][1]+period-1))
  }
  rows <- list.append(rows, newRow)
}
rows <- data.table::rbindlist(rows, use.names=TRUE)
```

The objective is to find the minimum and maximum indexes of the data to be taken into account from 'timeticks' and then find the lowest and highest values of data$value within that range of indexes.

Example of target result:

```
structure(list(start = c(1552820400000, 1552824000000, 1552820520000, 1552824000000, 1513846500000, 1552838520000), 
               end =   c(1552823999999, 1552827599999, 1513846579999, 1552824059999, 1513846559999, 1552838580000),
               highest = c(0.004, 0.00125, 0.0018),
               lowest = c(0.0011, 0.00125, 0.0018)), 
          row.names = c('start', 'end', 'lowest', 'highest'), 
          class = "data.frame")
```

How can I optimize this code ?

Comment: It would really help if we had a good idea what the data looked like. Can you provide a representative sample, using `dput(head(x))` (as many rows as needed to give us enough to work with)? Please paste that output directly into your question. (This is for both `data` and `array_starts` ... what is `datas`? `period`?)

Comment: BTW: no matter if you are using `data.frame`, `tibble`, or `data.table`, it is always bad to iteratively use `bind_rows`. Better to store them in a `list` (perhaps even using `lapply`, much better in a sense) and then do a single `data.table::rbindlist(x)` at the end. Also, is there a reason you are using `dplyr::bind_rows` on a `data.table` instead of `data.table::rbindlist`?

Comment: As a small point of etiquette, MD-FRA-83, it would be better for you if you remainder available and responsive for "a bit of time" after posting the question. If the question is poorly-phrased, it can quickly accrue down-votes and close-votes. More appropriate for this question, though: you have a fleeting window of opportunity to get a lot of views and potential answers ... once time has passed and it is no longer garnering that attention, you chances of getting a good answer decrease significantly. You aren't being rude here (sorry if I appear rude), it's just better if you're available.

Comment: @r2evans, yes, I'm sorry but it was very late and my brain was shouting to me to go to sleep...:-) I'm gonna answer all of your questions.

Comment: I've been there several times and understand. Just know that it's better if you can stick around once asking a question. (Sometimes I'll write the question, sleep on it, then look at it with a fresh mind, often able to self-answer before posting the question. It's one technique I employ imperfectly.)

Comment: I just added some variables content...

Comment: Still missing a little bit. `period`? Typo: `datas`? What is your expected output given your sample data?

Comment: (I think I had a poor choice of words before. "Etiquette", not as much, perhaps more "strategy". Speaking of sleep ...)

Comment: I have time-series data. Each $data element has a value. $period is a multiple of 60000 (milliseconds) to determine the window within which to look for $data elements.

Comment: Okay, so `period` (not within the frame) is just a time series of 60ms intervals for all data. Okay, what about `data` versus `datas`?

Comment: period can be anything multiple of 60000ms.
data and datas were the same (mistake)
I update the variable names and code since I'm trying to move forward...

Comment: Maybe can I precalculate a minimum and maximum indexes table for all $data related to timeticks, but I don't get how to do it ?

Comment: Bottom line: if I don't know what your variable `period` looks like, then it's hard to try to reproduce what you intend to do. An easy check to see if this is a reproducible question: start a new R session (`ls()` is empty), copy the code you placed here, then see if it does what you expect it to do. In this case, you'll still see `object 'datas' not found` and `object 'period' not found`.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Everything was still in memory, that's why you couldn't run the code. It should work now.